# How to fix gutenburg InnerBlocks to respond with RangeControl

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I'm using `RangeControl` in order to determine how many columns I should use on my `innerblock` template but the problem is it only returns the default value of the `rangecontrol` and the condition doesn't work.

Tried using the ternary conditioning.

```
<PanelBody>
    <RangeControl
        label="Columns"
        value={ props.attributes.columns }
        min={1}
        max={4}
        onChange={newColumns => { props.setAttributes({ columns: newColumns }); }} />
</PanelBody>


<div class={props.attributes.layout}>
    {

          ( props.attributes.columns == 1 ) ? 

          <InnerBlocks template={[
            [ 'cgb/columns' ],

        ]}
        />      
         : ( props.attributes.columns == 2 ) ? 
        <InnerBlocks template={[
            [ 'cgb/columns' ],
            [ 'cgb/columns' ],

        ]}
        />      
        : ( props.attributes.columns == 3 ) ?                           
        <InnerBlocks template={[
            [ 'cgb/columns' ],
            [ 'cgb/columns' ],
            [ 'cgb/columns' ]           
            ]}
            />              
        : "error"
    }
</div>
```

I expect the output to respond with the condition, for example my default `RangeControl` value is 3 so when I load the block it only returns 3 columns and I can't make it to return 2 or 1 columns using the `RangeControl`.

Answer (score 1):

You should call innerBlocks only once. And then set the template based on your range control value. 
Here an example to put before *return*:

```
    var TEMPLATE = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        var templateContent = [ 'cgb/columns', {} ];
        TEMPLATE.push(templateContent);
    }
```

And in InnerBlocks part you call that TEMPLATE

```
    ...
    <InnerBlocks
        template={ TEMPLATE }
    />
```